# Changing the margins to 2.5 cm in APA-6-Style Manuscript

Tags: margins, apa6

Is it possible to use specific margin sizes in an APA-6-Style manuscript with latex?
I want everything else to be APA6 style but the margin sizes. I would like them to be 2.5 cm instead of 2.54 cm(1 inch). Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Are you you using the `apa6` document class?

Comment: Yes, I'm using: \documentclass[11pt, a4paper,man,natbib, floatsintext]{apa6}

Comment: Then my answer should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `apa6` document class sets margins using the `geometry` package, so you can just add:

```
\geometry{margin=2.5cm}
```

to your preamble.